# Is there a way to prevent tidy from wrapping in an tag?

Tags: php, tidy

I am working on some test cases and `tidy`ing the output to compare to the ideal output.  But I am coming across an oddness where it wraps in the middle of tags.  Is there a configuration setting I am missing (other than turning off wrapping) to get this to break before on the tag not inside it?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input id="$nodeid[0]" /><input id=
      "$nodeid[1]" /><input id="$nodeid[2]" /><input id=
      "$nodeid[3]" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

My current config is.

```
$config = array(
           'indent'         => true,
           'output-xhtml'   => true,
           'literal-attributes'    => true, 
           'preserve-entities' =>true,
           'markup' => TRUE,
           'show-warnings' =>TRUE,
           'char-encoding' =>'utf8',
           'punctuation-wrap' => true,
           'wrap'           => 60);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the  `output-xhml => true` with `output-xml => true` works.